# Units of the rate constant for reactions whose order is greater than 1

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, units

In many textbooks, it is written that:

> The value of rate constant depends on the nature of the reactants, temperature and catalyst. It is independent of the concentration of the reactants.

However, the unit of the rate constant is

$$\left(\frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{l}}\right)^{1-n} \mathrm{s}^{-1}$$

where $n$ is the order of reaction.

Therefore, except for first order reactions, the unit of the rate constant will have a concentration term $\displaystyle\frac{\textrm{mol}}{\textrm{l}}$ for all other reactions. Does this contradict the statement given in books?

Comment: So what if it will have a concentration term?

Comment: Think of it like the equilibrium coefficient, the units don't realllly matter. Still use them to check your units and stuff.

Comment: @EashaanGodbole I think units matter. However, you can't tell from the units what a quantity depends on. Let's say I drive with a constant speed of 100 km/h on the freeway. Just because the units have the length-unit km in them does not mean my speed depends on how far I've already driven (or how long, for that matter). The idea of constant speed is that the ratio of distance and time is constant, even as time passes and you move along.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin So, rate constant does not depend on the concentration of reactants for all type of reactions including pseudo first order reactions?

Comment: @KarstenTheis I wasn't saying units don't matter in general--Units are *very* important and non-neglectable for most cases. I'm just saying they may not hold as much importance in this *specific* scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As an example if the reaction is $\ce{A + B -> C}$ the rate expression for the appearance of $\ce{C}$ is

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{C}]}{\mathrm dt} = +k[\ce{A}][\ce{B}].$$

The units have to be the same on both sides of this equation, these are concentration/time on the left and to be the same on the right the rate constant $k$ has to have units $(1/\text{concentration})(1/\text{time})$ usually expressed as $\mathrm{dm^3\,mol^{-1}\,s^{-1}}.$

It is true that the *numerical value* of the rate constant usually depends of several things such as temperature, but the units remain the same for each type of rate constant, 0<sup>th</sup>,  1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> simply because the rate equation units have to balance.

Comment: No, units does not remain the same for each type of reaction. Here you have assumed the order of the reaction w.r.t. both 'A' and 'B' as 1. So net order n= 1+1= 2.

Comment: @Apurvium You have probably mis-understood, I wrote that units have to be the same on both sides the the equation because the equation has to balance. By type of rate constant it is clear from what I wrote that all first order have the same units etc. etc.

Comment: But you have mentioned that "the units remain the same for each type of rate constant, 0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd simply because the rate equation units have to balance", so I assumed that 0, 1, 2, 3 refers to order. This makes the statement incorrect!

Comment: No, all reactions of 1 st order have the same units for the rate constant  and similarly for other orders, which is what 'same for each _type_ of rate constant' means.

Comment: OK. But my original query remains unanswered. Which is " Does rate constant depends on concentration of reactants for any type of reaction?"

Comment: No, you can see from the equation I give that $k$ is a constant independent of any concentration. The same is true for all other rate expressions excluding the pseudo rate constant that is sometimes used in special cases.

Comment: OK, so for pseudo first order reaction, the value of rate constant will depend on the concentration of reactant(s).

Comment: yes and only because one concentration is _vastly_ in excess of the other and does not change by any realistic amount while the reaction occurs.

Comment: Suppose, in the given reaction by you, the reactant 'B' is in excess. Therefore, the rate law for this pseudo first order reaction will be dx/dt = k[A], neglecting  [B] since it will remain unchanged during the reaction. So, why the value of 'k' will depend on [B] ?

Comment: In a bimolecular reaction where the rate is $k[A][B] $ if B has such a high concentration compared to A that A can react without affecting B to any great extent, then $k[B]$ is effectively constant and we can write rate as $k[A][B] \equiv  k'[A]$ where $k'$ is a pseudo rate constant. All this will be in your textbook.